# TSQL SELECT Prior Enrollment If

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Program enrollment creates a challenge in our system.  When a client is shifted from one staff to another, the system also un-enrolls the client from their program and re-enrolls the client into the program that same day.

OBJECTIVE: My query should identify the first enrollment date "p_effdt" (prior to any re-enrollments).  But, I do not want the MIN(p_effdt) because that might not reflect any actual lapses of enrollment.

EXAMPLE: Client Adam enrolls on 2/1/2013.  On 4/1/2013 he switches to a different staff so our system will un-enroll and re-enroll Adam on 4/1/2013.  The date I want to report for Adam is 2/1/2013. Client Eve enrolls on 2/1/2013 and then lapses on 5/1/2013 and re-enrolls on 7/1/2013.  The date I want to report for Eve is 7/1/2013.

```
SELECT client.c_id, c_ln + ', ' + c_fn AS 'Client', program.p_id, MIN(p_effdt) --that is wrong!
FROM client INNER JOIN program ON client.c_id = program.c_id
WHERE program.p_effdt BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '12.31.2013'
AND program.p_id = '1234'
GROUP BY client.c_id, c_ln, c_fn, program.p_id, p_effdt
ORDER BY client.c_id
```

The logic would be something like: if p_lpsdt = p_effdt then go to prior p_effdt and ask if p_lpsdt = p_effdt again ... Should I put that in the SELECT or use ROWCOUNT() or ...?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just tried the following and it might work, I'm checking it now.  But still eager to hear your thoughts.  Thanks.  , (SELECT MAX(p_effdt) WHERE p_effdt <> p_lapdt)

Comment: Now I am trying: WHERE ((program.p_effdt BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '12.31.2013') AND ((p_effdt <> p_lapdt) OR p_lapdt IS NULL))

Comment: I'm uncertain as to the terminology. Can a client enrol, re-enroll (switch) and then lapse? If so, I think you will retrieve their re-enrollment rather than their initial enrollment.

Comment: Try adding `AND program.p_effdt > (select isnull(max(p2.p_lpsdt), '1900/01/01') from program p2 where p2.p_id = program.p_id and p2.c_id = client.c_id)` to the where clause in the SQL in your question.  This should get you the min enrollment date that is greater than the last lapse date.

Comment: Thanks BateTech, but what I want the query to do is ignore any enrollment dates that equal a lapse date -- so, get MAX(p_effdt) where p_effdt <> p_lapsdt.

Comment: Please post the table structures -or a sample-; it will help us understand the problem and find a solution.

Comment: @PowderSnorkel it sounds like what you want is the first (min) enroll date AFTER the last (max) lapse date, is this correct?  If you use `SELECT MAX(p_effdt) ... WHERE p_effdt <> p_lapsdt` then your query is basically getting the max enroll date while ingoring any lapse date records, and won't work for a scenario where someone has 2 enrollment dates after a lapse date, i.e. enrolls on 1/1/13, lapses on 2/1/13, enrolls on 3/1/13, and then "switches to a different staff" and is re-enrolled on 4/1/13.  My query would return 3/1/13 in that case, your option using the max would return 4/1/13.

Comment: Also I just noticed, based on your requirements, I think you want to take `p_effdt` out of your `group by`.

Comment: @PowderSnorkel, what version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using SQL Server 2012 then you might be able to use the new LAG windowing function that allows you to access a prior row, which has the potential to greatly simplify this type of query: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is the modified query.  Assuming the requirement is to "get the first (min) enroll date AFTER the last (max) lapse date by client and program ID", then this should work. Check out this SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8dd02/2 ) for results and sample data with 3 test cases.

```
SELECT c.c_id, c_ln + ', ' + c_fn AS 'Client', p.p_id, MIN(p_effdt) as p_EffDt 
FROM #client c INNER JOIN #program p ON c.c_id = p.c_id
WHERE p.p_effdt BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '12.31.2013'
AND p.p_effdt > 
    (   select isnull(max(p2.p_lapsdt), '1900/01/01') 
        from #program p2 
        where p2.p_id = p.p_id and p2.c_id = c.c_id
    )
--AND p.p_id = 1 --commented out to run for all clients
GROUP BY c.c_id, c_ln, c_fn, p.p_id
ORDER BY c.c_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PowderSnorkel, I think you may have dismissed BateTech's suggestion prematurely.

Now, I'm not entirely certain of your grouping and Jayvee is right in that a schema and some test data might help us help you ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is great for mock-ups), but if you combine BateTech's suggestion with your own criteria, it'd work something like this.

```
SELECT 
  client.c_id, 
  c_ln + ', ' + c_fn AS 'Client', 
  program.p_id, 
  MIN(p_effdt)
FROM 
  client INNER JOIN program 
    ON client.c_id = program.c_id
WHERE 
  program.p_effdt BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '12.31.2013'
  AND program.p_id = '1234'
  AND program.p_effdt > (
    SELECT 
      ISNULL(MAX(p2.p_lpsdt), '1900/01/01') 
    FROM 
      program p2 
    WHERE 
      p2.p_id = program.p_id 
      AND p2.c_id = client.c_id)
GROUP BY 
  client.c_id, 
  c_ln, 
  c_fn, 
  program.p_id
ORDER BY 
  client.c_id
```

In the WHERE clause, we are a) requesting the effective date/s of the program records that are older than the last lapse (if applicable) and b) are not, themselves, lapses. Retaining the MIN in the select clause should ensure we get the earliest of these which handles cases where a client switches but doesn't let the original/previous enrolment lapse. I'm not sure if this is a valid case (you never answered my question), but it's probably worth handling.

Let us know if this gets you any closer.

Comment: Hi Zec, I am getting an empty set (no rows returned).  First, let me walk through your logic: select the earliest enrollment date that is after the latest lapse date (or after 1900/01/01 if null) where enrollment and lapse dates are not equal.  That sounds good, but I am not sure why that would return an empty set?  hmmm...

Comment: I'm guessing that p_lapsdt is NULL when not a lapse record, so `p_effdt <> p_lapsdt` would cause records that are not lapses to be excluded (b/c the expression `@Any_date_value <> NULL` always returns false, think of it as reading `any_date_value is not equal to some Unknown date value`). This would also cause any records that are lapses to be excluded if p_lapsdt always equals p_effdt for lapse records.  Hard to tell without sample data, table structure, and expected values for a given scenario.  See if the answer I just posted works. There is a link to a SQLFiddle w/ test data and results.

Comment: Yep, I even assumed lapse date could be NULL. I don't think there's a reason to check for inequality between dates anyway due to ensuring the returned  program records are newer than the most recent lapse.

Comment: @BateTech, I only carried on with your idea as it was hours since you made your suggestion and I figured a full answer might be more helpful. +1 to yours.